# Two input fields with keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields and i need a function that do something when the value of #name or #email was changed. My start doesn't really work.

```
$('#name').keyup( function() {
// OR
$('#email').keyup( function() {

    // DO SOMETHING

});
});
```

Comment: this should work. what is wrong??

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: He set the closing brackets wrong... this won't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use comma `,` to separate **[multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**:

```
$('#name,#email').keyup( function() {
    // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nested, the second call to the `$('#email')` keyup event will be executed *only if* a keyup event on `#name` was triggered.

The code should be something like this:

```
$('#name,#email').keyup( function() {
    // DO SOMETHING
});

$('#name,#email').on('keyup', function() {
    // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the keyup function wrongly which is why not working:

```
$('#name').keyup( function() {
// OR
}); //closing here
$('#email').keyup( function() {

    // DO SOMETHING

});
//}); not here
```

A better solution for multiple selectors use like @Felix:

```
$('#name,#email').keyup( function() {
    // DO SOMETHING
});
```